# cannot be cast to java.lang.Long Android SharedPreferences

Tags: android, casting, sharedpreferences

After a fresh install of my APP I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ... 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to 
java.lang.Long
```

The (Activity) code:

Initialization long (outside of onCreate):

```
long spinTimer = 0L;
```

Assign previous long val from pefs- or default to 0L (within onCreate):

```
spinTimer = settings.getLong("spinTimer", 0L);
```

Should be a long, where is the int coming from?

Other code references where the sharepref gets its values (all long):

```
if (item.equals("Select...")) {editor.putLong("spinTimer", 0L);}
if (item.equals("5 mins")) {editor.putLong("spinTimer", System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 60 * 1000));}
if (item.equals("10 mins")) {editor.putLong("spinTimer", System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 60 * 1000));}
if (item.equals("15 mins")) {editor.putLong("spinTimer", System.currentTimeMillis() + (15 * 60 * 1000));}
if (item.equals("30 mins")) {editor.putLong("spinTimer", System.currentTimeMillis() + (30 * 60 * 1000));}
if (item.equals("1 hour")) {editor.putLong("spinTimer", System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 60 * 1000));}
editor.commit();
spinTimer = settings.getLong("spinTimer", 0L);
```

After clearing APP data, all is good. Which I should not have to do each time I fresh install the APP.

How in the world is an int sneaking in there?

**Requested DEBUG INFO** - Not standard, but thought this should suffice:

Relevant lines of code (simple Activity) where the crash is occurring:

```
log.debug("***Activity Start***");
log.debug("OnCreateEnter");
SharedPreferences settings = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
log.debug("spinTimer: {}", spinTimer);
spinTimer = settings.getLong("spinTimer", 0L); // <-- APP crashes right here
```

Output:

```
***Activity Start***
OnCreateEnter
spinTimer: 0
```

1) Shouldn't the 2nd argument to .getLong (0L) be assigned to variable  (spinTimer) if nothing is assigned? I also tried '0'.

2) How is an int getting assigned? Both the key 'spinTimer' (0L) and var 'spinTimer' ('long spinTimer = 0L;') are initialized as longs.

3) If I clear the APP data (after the fresh install)- all is well;

4) And if I add the following lines of code before the above statements- all goes well (but this approach skews up my logic):

```
editor.putLong("spinTimer", spinTimer);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to 
java.lang.Long
```

Due to **`ClassCastException`** problem , You should use [**`Long.valueOf`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28long%29).

> Returns a Long instance representing the specified long value. If a
>   new Long instance is not required, this method should generally be
>   used in preference to the constructor Long(long), as this method is
>   likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by
>   caching frequently requested values. Note that unlike the
>   corresponding method in the Integer class, this method is not required
>   to cache values within a particular range.

```
editor.putLong("spinTimer", Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 60 * 1000))
```

Comment: Good catch. Perfect answer with helpful details.

Comment: @IntelliJ: Nice/Thanks! After I crashed last night, I had a dream of trying this out 1st thing this morning- thinking there was no other possible explanation. Thanks for the quick, very clear response. Upvoting, but will try/verify later. If I do not return- all was good (certain it will be).

Comment: Studio complains with: 'Unnecessary boxing of Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 60 * 1000)));'.Ignore?  Curious, if System.currentTimeMillis is already casted as long (along with everything else)- why is it required?

Comment: Search on google `Unnecessary boxing of Long.valueOf`

Comment: @IntelliJ Thanks will do. Even after adding the code, uninstalling APP/reinstalling - APP crashes with same error. Not sure how an int is being casted anywhere in code.

Comment: Debug please. Add Breakpoint. I will check my answer next day.

Comment: @IntelliJ: DEBUG added to question. Thanks!

Comment: Odd, I build a DEBUG version of the APP- and the issue does not exist!

Comment: @XO. OMG! Very strange case.